# Flex4 TabBar skinning

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, tabbar, skinning

I have trying to skin TabBar and NavigatorContent.

[Please see image for explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5Lsa.jpg) - All tabs are transparent (alpha 0.6) and also their borders.

How can I remove top border from NavigatorContent under selected buttonTab ?

Answer (score 2):

How its must be:

[image: How its must be]

Trying to use BlendMode.ERASE:

Application code:

```
...  
<s:SkinnableContainer blendMode="layer" ... skinClass="skins.TabBorder">
    <mx:ViewStack ...>
        <s:NavigatorContent label="Search" skinClass="skins.TabSkin" /> 
        <s:NavigatorContent label="Customer Info" skinClass="skins.TabSkin" /> 
    </mx:ViewStack>
    <s:TabBar dataProvider="{myViewStack}"  ... />
</s:SkinnableContainer>
...
```

skins.TabBorder:

```
<s:Rect left="0" right="0" top="25" bottom="0" radiusX="6" topLeftRadiusX="0">
    <s:stroke>
        <s:SolidColorStroke color="#ffffff" alpha="0.3" />
    </s:stroke>
</s:Rect>
```

skins.TabBarButtunSkin:

```
<!-- its black rect which clears all under -->
<s:Rect blendMode="erase" top="0" left="0" right="0" bottom="-2" topLeftRadiusX="6" topRightRadiusX="6" includeIn="selectedStates, overStates">
    <s:fill>
        <s:SolidColor color="#000000" />
    </s:fill>
</s:Rect>
```

Perhaps there is an easier way?

Comment: I think you already using easier way, cause all other will be few harder, and not very good solutions in design/view logic.

Answer (score 0):

`<... borderSides=”left bottom right” borderStyle=”solid” borderThickness=”1″ ...>`

also you can write your own skin

or extend the component itself

Comment: In this case border will be removed from top side. But I need to remove border just under the selected button.

Comment: just apply this style in case of selected state. Are you familiar with states?

Comment: Yes, I know about states. And I trying to use advice, but... see next post with explanation.